# Pair a random image with a random quote and assign that pair a unique url

Tags: php, random

I would like to pair a set of pictures with a list of quotes each pulled randomly from their lists and assign that pair a unique url. Much like the [The Nietzsche Family Circus](http://www.losanjealous.com/nfc/) does.

I'm pretty sure he is using php to pull randomly for the two lists and creating th url with those the picture and quotes unique identifiers.

Is there anybody who could help me get started on replicating this concept? Thanks.

Comment: Which part, specifically, is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a database. If you create a table in the database with one column for the unique url identifying the pair, one column for an image url, and one column for the quote text you could then do something like the following:

```
$quoteArray = array(); //in reality this would be filled with your quotes
$imageArray = array(); //this would be filled with your image urls
$pairs = array();
while(count($quoteArray) > 0 && count($imageArray) > 0) {
    $quoteIndex = rand(0, count($quoteArray) - 1); //get some random indexes
    $imageIndex = rand(0, count($imageArray) - 1);
    $pairs[] = array('quote' => $quoteArray[$quoteIndex], 'image' => $imageArray[$imageIndex]);
    unset($quoteArray[$quoteIndex]); //keep us from using the same quote twice
    unset($imageArray[$imageIndex]); //same goes for the images
}

//this assumes your table has an autoincremeting id field
$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO awesomeTable (quote, image) VALUES( :quote , :image )");
//$connection is a PDO which you would have created earlier...look in the php manual for information on setting this up

foreach($pairs as $pair) {
    $uniqueId = sha1($quote . $image);
    $stmt->execute(array(':quote' => $pair['quote'], ':image' => $pair['image']));
}
```

Then, to get a random url out:

```
$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM awesomeTable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$record = $result->fetch();
//record will contain either an object (accessed by $row->url, $row->quote, etc) or an
//associative array (accessed by $row['url'], $row['quote'], etc) depending on how you
//set up the PDO
```

Your page that would serve these up (images.php) would simply take an id passed to it (which would be unique because it was being autoincremented) and query the database to get the row (and therefore the quote and image) associated with that id.